# Auto-append an autonumbered TaskID to Outlook Exchange (shared) mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, append

Very similar requirement at first glance to Luke123's 'Append a Tag to Outlook' request.
Here, I need to append an autonumber Task ID (which is specific only to this requirement) into the Subject line of an Outlook Exchange (shared) mailbox.

This therefore needs to a) autonumber sequentially and b) run automatically as the e-mails land.

Pretty certain rules for shared mailboxes run server-side and are locked down by the business.

All ideas/help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This code will most likely need to be tweaked but should do what you want. You may need to take the existing Inbox items and give them a task ID in order to get the ball rolling. See my comments for explanation of the code as well as places you need to edit.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  ' edit this line to reflect the actual mailbox name as displayed in Outlook
  Set Items = Session.Folders("Mailbox - My Shared Mailbox").Folders("Inbox")
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim firstObj As Object
  Dim i As Long
  Dim firstMsg As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim currentTaskID As String
  Dim nextTaskID As Long

  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then ' it's an email
    Set msg = item

    ' get first email from Inbox to determine next task ID
    Do Until TypeName(firstObj) = "MailItem" Or i = Session.Folders("Mailbox - My Shared Mailbox").Folders("Inbox").Items.Count
      i = i + 1
      ' might have to start at item #2?
      Set firstObj = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(i)
    Loop

    ' typecast the object to mailitem for Intellisense
    If TypeName(firstObj) = "MailItem" Then
      Set firstMsg = firstObj
    Else
      ' display messagebox?
      Goto ProgramExit
    End If

    ' get task id and calculate next value, let's assume it's the last three chars of subject
    ' Ex: Subject: Incoming Email - TaskId: 001
    currentTaskID = Right$(firstMsg.Subject, 3)
    nextTaskID = CLng(currentTaskID) + 1

    ' put next task ID number into new email's subject
    With msg
      .Subject = msg.Subject & " - TaskId: " & nextTaskID
      .Save
    End With

  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks JP, and my apols for not getting to this sooner.  I got dragged off onto another project at work and have only just returned to this issue.
Really appreciate the help.